# SQLAlchemy database in meta

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

How can I specify other db name without writing it in config file?
Can I set db name in fields of model class? Something like:

```
__tablename__ = '"db_name"."db_table"'
```

It worked in django models (Meta db_table property), not sure if it will work in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: You might be able to use the `schema` parameter: `__table_args__ = {'schema': 'db_name'}`. Which database are you using?

Comment: Miikka, thanks, it worked!